# Транспонирование квадратной матрицы

Tags: python, list, матрицы, список

Я хочу сделать вложенный список из столбцов матриц одинаковой длинны и ширины,например скажем матрица 3х3:

```
013
123
239
```

Я получаю из неё список такой:

```
[[0,1,3],
 [1,2,3],
 [2,3,9]]
```

Я хочу из него получить это:

```
[[0,1,2],
 [1,2,3],
 [3,3,9]]
```

Язык 
Помогите плз)
P.S. сделайте пожалуйста так чтобы для всех вариаций матрицы это работало,типо 5х5,7х7 и тд

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [[0,1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,9]]
b = list(map(list,zip(*a)))
print(b)
```

Вывод:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [3, 3, 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать библиотеку *numpy* с функцией *transpose*

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,1,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,9]])
a = a.transpose()
print(a)
```